# Cumulated and bounded sum of values on PgSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recursion, sum

I am struggling writing a query on PgSQL.

My table has values, and I have to cumulate its values, but the result must be bounded (between 0 and 30 in that case).

Here is the dataset and expected result:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
| id | value  | expected_cumulated_sum_with_limits |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 |      3 |                                  3 |
|  2 |      4 |                                  7 |
|  3 |     -2 |                                  5 |
|  4 |    -28 |                                  0 |
|  5 |     45 |                                 30 |
|  6 |     -3 |                                 27 |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
```

I tried some queries with WINDOW (but I can do only a sum, without 0,30 limits) and some recursive CTE (but I'm not sure it is the good way to go).

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by must be bounded between 0 and 30? What if the value is very large and will cause the cumulative sum to fall below 0 or above 30?

Comment: for row `id=5`, why `expected_cumulated_sum_with_limits` have value 30 and not 22 ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze The row before's adjusted cumulative is 0, so the 45 is added to the 0 and not the actual cumulative

Comment: I think the easiest is to use cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that good with recursive CTE, so there might be better approach, but this works:

```
CREATE TABLE cum_bounded (id int4, value int4);
INSERT INTO cum_bounded VALUES (1,3), (2,4), (3,-2), (4,-28), (5,45), (6,-3);
```

If ID have no gaps and you want to calculate values ordering by ID:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cum AS (
  (SELECT c.id, c.value, c.value AS cum_value FROM cum_bounded AS c ORDER BY c.id LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.value,
         CASE WHEN cum.cum_value + c.value < 0 THEN 0
              WHEN cum.cum_value + c.value > 30 THEN 30
              ELSE cum.cum_value + c.value END
  FROM cum_bounded AS c
  JOIN cum ON cum.id = c.id - 1
)
SELECT * FROM cum;
```

If ID have gaps, then check what is the next ID (ordering by ID). Could also calculate `row_number()` instead:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cum AS (
  WITH cb AS (SELECT id, lead(id) OVER(ORDER BY c.id) AS next_id, c.value FROM cum_bounded AS c)
  (SELECT c.id, c.next_id, c.value, c.value AS cum_value FROM cb AS c ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.next_id, c.value,
         CASE WHEN cum.cum_value + c.value < 0 THEN 0
              WHEN cum.cum_value + c.value > 30 THEN 30
              ELSE cum.cum_value + c.value END
  FROM cb AS c
  JOIN cum ON cum.next_id = c.id
)
SELECT id, value, cum_value FROM cum;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/UCEDK41004

Comment: Very nice, recursive was indeed the good way to go, thanks @Łukasz-kamiński !